# Adding a UITabBarController counter that looks like the Inbox items waiting counter

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

Does anyone have a sample, or link to one, of how to create a counter that looks like the Inbox counter?

Any help appreciated // :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does `UITabBarItem badgeValue` do what you're wanting?

Comment: Awesome! That's it exactly! Thanks // :)